# solving a looping issue in java language

Tags: java, xml, database, loops, while-loop

how ya'll doing?

I seem to be having a basic problem with infinite loops in java...while using netbeans. I am inserting data into a table which writes all the data into an xml file. The xml file is being written but it goes into an infinite loop while it should be adding to the table and extending itself for as long as I am adding in new values for each line of entry. So I can't even enter a line of data into the table which prints the row without the program going into a loop.

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    DefaultTableModel model=(DefaultTableModel) jTable_tableDemo.getModel();

    model.addRow(new Object[]{jTextField_Name.getText(),jTextField_Address.getText(),jTextField_Phone.getText()});

    try {   
            int i = 0;
            Document doc = new Document();

    Element theRoot = new Element("models");

    doc.setRootElement(theRoot);
            while (jTextField_Name.getText()!=""){
            i++;    

            Element models = new Element("model"+i);

    Element name1 = new Element("name"+i);
    Element address1 = new Element("address"+i);
    Element phone1 = new Element("phone"+i);

    name1.setAttribute("name_id",""+i);

    name1.addContent(new Text(jTextField_Name.getText()));



    address1.setAttribute("address_id",""+i);

        address1.addContent(new Text(jTextField_Address.getText()));

            phone1.setAttribute("phone_id",""+i);

        phone1.addContent(new Text(jTextField_Phone.getText()));


            models.addContent(name1);

    models.addContent(address1);

            models.addContent(phone1);

    theRoot.addContent(models);

    XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat());

    xmlOutput.output(doc, new FileOutputStream(new File("./src/jdomMade.xml")));

    System.out.println("Wrote to File");
            }


}                                        
catch (Exception ex){

        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

[Pic of Table Before Entering Data In Fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FYV8.jpg)

[Pic of Table After Entering Data In Fields When Application Freezes After Going On An Infinite Loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WwaMj.jpg)
Here's the XML file that is printed out for the jdomMade.xml file:

Please let me know how I can solve this problem by removing the infinite loop and printing only the number of times I enter data in the table. Thanks a lot.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<models>
  <model1>
    <name1 name_id="1">sdgsdfg</name1>
    <address1 address_id="1">sdgsdg</address1>
    <phone1 phone_id="1">sdgsg</phone1>
  </model1>
```

.....
till   till model infinity...

any way i can resolve it so that there is no infinite loops and the only data that gets transferred and printted to the jdomMade.xml file is what I enter in the table?

all of your help would greatly be appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/37495159/1030675

Comment: Please break down your code to where the error is occurring and post the error or the logcat. That helps to identify the problem easily.

Answer (score 0):

You are opening a loop with the following condition

```
 while (jTextField_Name.getText()!="")
```

And then adding values to your table. 
But once the values are added, you are not modifying the `jTextField_Name` and thus the condition always holds true and your code enters an infinite loop.

Change your try block to something like this

```
       Document doc = new Document();

    Element theRoot = new Element("models");

    doc.setRootElement(theRoot);
            i++;    

            Element models = new Element("model"+i);

    Element name1 = new Element("name"+i);
    Element address1 = new Element("address"+i);
    Element phone1 = new Element("phone"+i);

    name1.setAttribute("name_id",""+i);

    name1.addContent(new Text(jTextField_Name.getText()));



    address1.setAttribute("address_id",""+i);

        address1.addContent(new Text(jTextField_Address.getText()));

            phone1.setAttribute("phone_id",""+i);

        phone1.addContent(new Text(jTextField_Phone.getText()));


            models.addContent(name1);

    models.addContent(address1);

            models.addContent(phone1);

    theRoot.addContent(models);

    XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter(Format.getPrettyFormat());

    xmlOutput.output(doc, new FileOutputStream(new File("./src/jdomMade.xml")));

    System.out.println("Wrote to File");

    //clearing fields
    jTextField_Name.setText("");
    jTextField_Address.setText("");
    jTextField_Phone.setText("");
```

Make `i` as a global variable set to zero.

You are creating the same document again and so it will overwrite the previous values. Create a File type global variable and then use it like this

```
xmlOutput.output(doc, new FileOutputStream(myFile));
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: thnx lemme check now

Comment: should i remove the while loop then?

Comment: i do that but then it doesn't print EVERY SINGLE line or ROW in the table onto the xml - JUST the LAST line or ROW...any other ways u can help out? any other options?

Comment: same old same old...tried it again...same old! nothing works! :(((

Comment: You have to `append` data to your xml. You can find tutorials that explain how to add data to already created xml. If you feel your question has been answered, please mark this post as the answer

Comment: can u just append data for me please?

Comment: check this out http://www.coderanch.com/t/561569/XML/Appending-data-existing-XML-file